# Blacken installed but is giving the error that is isn't installed

Tags: python

I am running Emasc 26.2 on Windows 10 and have installed black via pip and installed blacken via melpa but when I enable `blacken-mode` it doesn't change any of the formatting even when I intentionally mess it up and when trying to enable `elpy-black-fix-code` it gives the error of `Elpy error: black not installed.`Am I using it incorrectly? I have also tried `blacken-buffer` and I get `Searching for program: No such file or directory, black`. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check `M-x elpy-config` to see which python env you’re using and if black is found.

Comment: @al0 I am using `C:/Windows/py.exe` and it is showing that Jedi, Rope, Autopep8, Yapf and Black aren't found but I have installed those via pip. How would I change the environment inside of Emacs?

Comment: So I changed it to pythonw (or something like that) and it is showing that they are now found but when trying to run blacken-mode it still gave me the error. EDIT: I just had to restart everything so now it is working. Thank you for the help!!!